# Change background of Input

Tags: css, sapui5

I start from this default theme (blucristal)

[image]
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputAssisted/preview

Now I want change the background of the editable input from white to (for example) yellow. How Can I do?

I would like use Ui theme designer but I can't find the correct property to change

Comment: I stumbled onto this question, and don't really know sapui/openui, but if you have access to CSS styles, the background is located on the class `.sapMinputBaseInner` so you would need something like this in css:
`.sapMInputBaseInner{background:yellow};` Didn't list as answer because I'm talking out of my ass. lol

Comment: this question need's to be close

Answer (score 0):

Any visual customization of standard controls can be done with help of CSS.
Redefine property of standard class

```
.sapMInputBaseInner{
  background-color: yellow  !important;
};
```

It will change background color for every intup. Or you can create your own CSS class

```
.UserClass .sapMInputBaseInner{
  background-color: yellow  !important;
};
```

And using method addStyleClass() add "UserClass" only to specific elements.

Comment: Thankyou @Vitaliy, but I want change background color only for editable Input.

Answer (score 0):

You may use CSS pseudo class for this purpose. Like this

```
form input[type=text]:focus{
background-color:red;
}
```

It will change the background-color of textbox from white to red whenever you click on it.

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/e284q9fv/